# Tricky Past Exam Question regarding Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a given vector $u$ in $\mathbb R^n$ with unit norm $\|u\|_2=1$ let $$H=I-2uu^T$$

$a)$ Determine all eigenvalues and associated eigenvectors of $H$

My attempt was to assume $u=\begin{bmatrix}{\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}\\{\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}\end{bmatrix}$ and then calculate $uu^T$, then evaluate $H$ and then its eigenvalues so on but obviously my assumption is incorrect so how should I go about it?

$\space$

$b)$ For a given $x \in \mathbb R^n$ how are $x$ & $Hx$ related to each other?

This one I simply don't understand...

Any help with the first one since perhaps it is the key to understanding the second one.

Comment: Try two things: (1) Compute $Hu$. (2) Compute $Hv$ for $v$ being any vector orthogonal to $u$.

Comment: But what would $u$ be? There are so many possibilities how do I generalize them?

Comment: Isn't $u$ a fixed vector of norm 1 by hypothesis?

Comment: But the components are not fixed?

Comment: You can calculate $Hu$ without knowing how exactly $u$ looks like: $Hu= Iu -2uu^T u = u  -2u(u^Tu) = u-2u=-u$ because $u^Tu = ||u||_2^2=1$. And if $v$ is orthogonal to $u$ we have $u^Tv=0$ and therefore $Hv=v$. That already gives you two eigenvalues. In fact, those are the only ones...

Comment: Thank you, @Lukas your solution makes the most sense but still how would you calculate the eigenvectors when you only have the Eigenvalues and no matrix? Like how can I find the solutions of the null space of $H - I \lambda$ using the eigenvalues $\lambda$ when I don't even know what its entries are? So far I have only been taught this one method to do so...

Comment: Or would  it be sufficient to just say: $$H - I \lambda = -2uu^T$$

Comment: Every vector is an eigenvector of the identity matrix so you can put $I$ aside and focus on the $uu^T$ part. As recommended above, multiply that by $u$ on the one hand or any vector orthogonal to it on the other hand.


Keep in mind you're looking for a vector that when you multiply it by your matrix you get a multiple of the same vector (possibly zero). Forget the usual 'method'
Your 'assumption' in part (a) is a good example to consider.


For part (b) consider the two distinct possibilities, $x$ is parallel to $u$ or orthogonal to it.

Comment: was my answer very complicated ?

Comment: @Physor Yes, in the sense that the course I am taking didn't explain this stuff to me in the terms you used! However, I wanted to accept Lukas answer or idl answer but they only wrote the comments which is why I accepted Mano's answer which is an alternate solution to the others...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate $H^2$. It’s identity. Hence eigenvalues are $\pm1$.